# MembershipUser.ResetPassword generates invalid password

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have an MVC 3 application that has, on at least one occasion, generated a password that is not valid based on the passwordStrengthRegularExperssion setting.  The setting in the config `<membership>` section is:

passwordStrengthRegularExpression="^(?=.{7,20}$)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\d\W]).*$"

meaning that we require at least one upper-case and one lowercase letter and one special character.

The generated password in this case was "mg$[v9p}" - no upper-case letter.  Changing one of the letters to upper-case makes it pass the regex test.

Has anyone seen similar behavior or does anyone have an idea what might be going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the MembershipProvider you are using. Calling `MembershipUser.ResetPassword` will ultimately result in a call to `MembershipProvider.ResetPassword`.

That means:

- If you have implemented your own `MembershipProvider` you can look there to see what happens.
- If you are using Microsofts `SqlMembershipProvider` than this note on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.resetpassword%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) maybe answers your question:

> The random password created by the ResetPassword method is not guaranteed to pass the regular expression in the PasswordStrengthRegularExpression property. However, the random password will meet the criteria established by the MinRequiredPasswordLength and MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters properties.

Comment: Thanks, bertl - that is likely to be the issue.  I am using the MySqlMembershipProvider.  Kind of a crazy thing.  I'd rather they just not implement the functionality than implement it incorrectly.